# BadImage Error When Loading Tiff CCITTv4 Via SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap.FromWicBitmap

Tags: c#, image, tiff, direct2d, sharpdx

I'm using SharpDX and its accompanying WIC and Direct2D wrappers to do some serverside image manipulation.

The following code works great with JPEG images and is modeled after the SharpDX docs and [this Microsoft sample using D2D directly via C++](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Imaging-Component-c5191dfc#content).

However, I get a BadImage error when I try to load a TIFF CCITT (bitonal 1bpp) image. The *BadImage* error is only thrown at `EndDraw`, (which happens later on in the commented `DrawEndorsement` function), or at this line of code which I inserted to make the point at which the issue occurs more obvious:

```
SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap bitmap = SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap.FromWicBitmap(_renderTarget, _wicBitmap);
```

The JPEG image I pass in gets to this point and continues with no issues, but the TIFF I pass in gets to this point and causes `FromWicBitmap` to barf with a BadImage error.

I'm using `FormatConverter` to convert the TIFF/JPEG pixel formats to an appropriate and supported D2D pixel format, and the converter does change the pixel format GUID for both images, but, again, `FromWicBitmap` barfs only on the TIFF.

I assumed I was doing something wrong with conversion or misusing SharpDX/D2D, but when I built and ran the aforementioned Microsoft C++ D2D image viewer sample, it loaded and rendered this **same** TIFF file with no errors. I double checked the sample's code to verify that I was using all the same pixel formats, options, etc, and it looks like I'm doing almost exactly the same thing with SharpDX that the sample is doing with D2D directly.

Clearly Direct2D doesn't like the pixel format of the TIFF image that WIC is handing it, but why didn't the MS sample exhibit the same behavior, and why didn't `FormatConverter` fix it?

1. Am I missing something that the D2D sample code is doing?
2. Am I missing some trick with SharpDX?
3. Is this a SharpDX bug?

Thanks!

```
public byte[] BuildImage(byte[] image, Format saveFormat)
{
    SharpDX.WIC.Bitmap _wicBitmap;
    WicRenderTarget _renderTarget;
    BitmapFrameDecode bSource;
    FormatConverter converter = new FormatConverter(_factoryManager.WicFactory);


    using (MemoryStream systemStream = new MemoryStream(image))
        using (WICStream wicStream = new WICStream(_factoryManager.WicFactory, systemStream))
        {
            BitmapDecoder inDecoder = new BitmapDecoder(_factoryManager.WicFactory, wicStream, DecodeOptions.CacheOnLoad);
            if (inDecoder.FrameCount > 0)
            {
                bSource = inDecoder.GetFrame(0);
                converter.Initialize(bSource, SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppPRGBA, BitmapDitherType.Solid, null, 0.0f, BitmapPaletteType.MedianCut);
                _imageWidth = bSource.Size.Width;
                _imageHeight = bSource.Size.Height;

            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("No frames found!");
            }
        }

    _wicBitmap = new SharpDX.WIC.Bitmap(
            _factoryManager.WicFactory,
            converter,
            BitmapCreateCacheOption.CacheOnDemand
            );

    _renderTarget = new WicRenderTarget(_factoryManager.D2DFactory, _wicBitmap, new RenderTargetProperties());

    SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap bitmap = SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap.FromWicBitmap(_renderTarget, _wicBitmap);

    //DrawEndorsement(_renderTarget);

    _renderTarget.Dispose();
    bSource.Dispose();
    converter.Dispose();

    return SaveImage(saveFormat, _wicBitmap);
}
```

Comment: Could you try to remove both using? (no dispose WicStream at all) afair, I suspect that the converter is requiring the stream to be still opened.

Comment: I actually discovered that in testing when I noticed JPEG image corruption. Turns out it also manifested as a Badimage error with TIFFs. Derp. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As xoofx pointed out, turns out that this was caused by my disposing of the WIC/MemoryStreams underlying the FormatConverter while it was still in use.

This was causing JPEGs to be corrupted on write, and weirdly causing the TIFFs to fail even before that.

Extended the using scope accordingly and that fixed it.